# PHP json_decode() not working

Tags: php, json

I have a problem I am getting a json file I can echo it and it looks like this

```
[{"sys_data":"0MxPPaza","date":"2015-02-15","objective":"VIDEO"}]
```

in my code I am doing this

```
$json = FROM THE SERVER;
$obj = json_decode($json);
$res = $obj->["objective"];
echo $res;
```

res is NULL obj is NULL also

Comment: try `echo json_last_error_msg()`. What do you get?

Comment: Json string is valid. But I'm not sure about `$res = $obj->["objective"];` construction.

Comment: if `$obj` is `null`, then the json string is not valid at all. Try to display $json. make sure it is really valid.

Comment: @Leggendario json_last_error_msg() returns No errors

SergeyChizhik if I echo only obj it is also null

Comment: Client has done something on their server and the json is not working I still do not understand why there were no errors in the json_last_error_msg() if json was not good.

Answer (score 2):

Your `json_decode` call returns an array, with one member.

Here is a dump of your json object:

`array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[10]
      public 'sys_data' => string '0MxPPaza' (length=8)
      public 'date' => string '2015-02-15' (length=10)
      public 'objective' => string 'VIDEO' (length=5)`

so replace this line:

```
$res = $obj->["objective"];
```

With this:

```
$res = $obj[0]->objective;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `[]` quotes to `{}`. Like `$res = $obj[0]->{"objective"};`

Or you may use assoc array convertation instead of object:

```php
$json = FROM THE SERVER;
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$res = $obj["objective"];
echo $res;`
```